# PHP script using ssh2_scp_send Fails to create remote file

Tags: php

I'm trying to transfer files to a shared hosting account (godaddy) and it's failing:

**Warning: ssh2_scp_send(): Failure creating remote file: failed to send file in 'local/file/path'**

I have SSH2 installed and the connection is working. I even ran a ssh2_exec command to see if I can affect the remote server and I was able to create a directory. *I also successfully used scp directly on the command line going both ways*... As a further troubleshooting attempt, I reversed the file paths and created a remote server file for it to attempt downloading, I get this error:

**failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

I called the host to make sure I'm using the correct absolute file path, I've tried many variations, and I still get this error. I think my issue lies somewhere with the remote file path.

The problem code is below:

```
$localpath=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/local_file_path/' ;

$remotepath = 'website.com/public_html/folder/' ;

$connection = ssh2_connect('website.com', 22);

ssh2_auth_password($connection,'username','password' );

ssh2_scp_send($connection,"$localpath"."SUCCESS.txt", "$remotepath"."SUCCESS.txt", 0644);
```

I am also having issues trying to use sftp via PHP. I read elsewhere on the web that you have to use double quotes on the file paths, whenever they fail, the printed path appears correct, but perhaps I'm missing something?

**UPDATE**

I logged into the shared hosting account via sftp with filezilla and discovered that, when copied, the full url path is different then what I was being given when logged in threw regular ftp. I can now upload a file, but, I can't seem to download just yet, ironically... I still get the error about not being able to locate the file path on the remote server.

Answer (score 5):

**ssh2_scp_send need absolute path**, I solved my issue by using `pwd` where I need to send my files. `~/` dont works either, it's not an absolute path.

The bottom comment on this page http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php refers to a problem you might be having.

I suggest that, use [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) or ssh2_sftp

**Interesting topics:**

- [Uploading files with SFTP & phpseclib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572314/uploading-files-with-sftp) interesting debate with good informations.
- [How to SFTP with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689540/how-to-sftp-with-php)